# bootstrap make input act like text link

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

If you take a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5g45h7tk/) you'll see C is way to the right even though for the most part it looks like the rest of the buttons. On my site it isn't as exaggerated but I do see a space (or two) and it bothers me. How do I set it so the second C looks looks like the one on the first row?

```
<a href="/" class="btn btn-lg">A</a>
<a href="/" class="btn btn-lg">B</a>
<a href="/" class="btn btn-lg">C</a>
<br>
<a href="/" class="btn btn-lg">A</a>
<a href="/" class="btn btn-lg">B</a>
<input class="btn btn-lg btn-link" value="C">
```

Answer (score 2):

add this to your CSS

```
.btn {
  width: 50px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4zhvb402/

or change this

```
.btn {
  text-align:left;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tgesvue7/

Answer (score 0):

It is an text input element, you should set it's size:

```
size="1"
```

wich makes the size 1 character.

Furthermore every browser renders it differently